# No foreign key restraints on a temporary table? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I know that a a temporary table will only exist for as long as a session of SQL Server is open, but why can't you have foreign key restraints on them?

Comment: can you share the reason for doing this?

Comment: My reason was for a user to create their own miniature version of a larger dataset online, ad hoc.  Say if someone wanted to do some simple queries and understand a little about how a database works.  It would give whomever played around with it a chance to make their own unique mini database and understand relational theory a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create foreign keys between tables in tempdb.  For example, try this:

```
use tempdb

create table parent
(
    parent_key int primary  key clustered
)

create table child
(
    child_key int primary key clustered,
    child_parent_key int
)
alter table child add constraint fk_child_parent foreign key (child_parent_key) references parent(parent_key)

insert into parent(parent_key) select 1
insert into child(child_key, child_parent_key) select 1, 1
insert into child(child_key, child_parent_key) select 2, 2 -- this fails because of the FK constraint

drop table child
drop table parent
```

Comment: The code above actually fails due to a primary key violation on the child table. If you amend it SQL tells you it does not enforce local or global temporary table foreign key.

Comment: @ddecasse: Thank you, I corrected the code.  When I run the corrected code, I get a standard FK violation.  What SQL Server version are you on?

Comment: @ddecasse: Did you change the code to use a temporary #Table?  When I use a standard table, SQL Server is enforcing the foreign keys.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine this scenario: You create a foreign key relationship from your temp table to a concrete table's key. One of the restrictions on a foreign key relationship is that you cannot delete a row from a key table that is depended upon by your temp table. Now, generally when you create foreign key relationships you know to delete the dependent table rows before deleting the related rows in the key table, but how does a stored procedure or any other call into the database know to delete rows from your temp table? Not only is it impossible to discover spurious foreign key dependencies, other sessions could not reach your temp table even if it could discover the relationship. This leads to spurious failures in delete statements as foreign key constraints restrict the key table for dependent rows.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you can't have cross-database foreign key constraints and temp tables technically are created in the TempDB database.

Unless you mean between a temp table and another temp table... but really there's lots of issues you get into when you talk about those kind of constraints on a temp table.

Comment: I was talking about temp tables with another temp table.  Daydreaming about things down the road I might want to do.