# join performance temp table in sql

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-execution-plan, query-performance, sql-tuning

In my database for somereasons not all table have foreign key
then for have  a better performance I used a select into (with data filtered) in a temp table , I did this for the tables I'll use for to have a better performance but now....

In the final result when I need do join between those table (temp table can't have foreign key, isn't it?) do not have foreign key I got "Merge Join" (I understand they are caused because my temp table does not have foreign key)

[image: Merge Join]

(If you dont see the pic I reupload it at here)
https://ibb.co/f0XRHv

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is (other than improve performance) but you can create indexes on temp tables, which might help with your temp table joins.  I think SQL Server will try to create any missing indexes for you on temp tables but you might need a larger number of rows before it decides its worth it.

Comment: Why do you think merge join is bad?

Comment: @Alex may be is not bad, but if they have foreign key, this will be faster yet.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like suggested in the following answer?

[No foreign key restraints on a temporary table? SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10936627/4302116)

Comment: are they temp tables? can an user with read permission use "use tempdb

create table parent
(
    parent_key int primary  key clustered
)"??????